# How to get an exact audio channel layout info by ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

How to get a audio channel layout info by ffmpeg?
For example,if audio is 5.1 then I want to get info following like 
FL+FR+FC+LFE+BL+BR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A roundabout method is to use `ffprobe` to get the numerical channel layout:

```
$ ffprobe -v error -show_entries stream=channel_layout -of csv=p=0 input.wav
  5.1
```

Then refer to `ffmpeg -layouts`:

```
$ ffmpeg -v error -layouts | awk '/5.1 /{print $2}'
  FL+FR+FC+LFE+BL+BR
```

Comment: thanks for your answer so much
I have another question: what if a layout is in wrong order?       
like the standard 5.1 is  FL+FR+FC+LFE+BL+BR
so could it happen if it become FR+BL+FR+FC+LFE+BR?
could we detect this kind situation

Comment: @xinxu That should be asked as a new question because it is a different issue.

Comment: thx for notice,I will accept this answer and post a new question